# Deploy Django app as a DigitalOcean's Cloud function?

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

The Scenario is, I want to deploy my Django application as a PaaS cloud function of the Django application. I have tried to search over the internet but come up with nothing. If this is possible, what will be the complications? Do I need to write the application from scratch again in vanilla Python for deploying it to the Cloud function?

Comment: They have a tutorial on deploying Django to their platform [here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/).

Comment: @NickODell, a quick question. So, the app platform and DO cloud function are different or same?

Comment: Different, I think. I've never used either. But if I had a choice, I would probably choose the one which has been done before.

Comment: Actually, this is my client's requirement that he wants to serve the Django application to DO cloud function.

Comment: That's why I'm curious if they have any difference in between.

Comment: Looking at how they're [pricing](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/functions) their function product, it seems like the way it's priced basically requires them to preempt your Django function whenever it's idle. I don't know if they do that, but *if* they do, cold start performance is going to suck.